# Can access services on my machine by localhost:port but cannot by ip:port

Tags: 14.04, networking, server

I wanted to access my machine's http rest service (exposed on port 5000) but I could only do it via accessing `localhost:5000` but not via `192.168.1.1:5000` where `192.168.1.1` is my IP.

I tried after that

```
nc -l localhost 5001
```

and

```
nc localhost 5001 // works 
nc 192.168.1.1 5001 //doesn't work
```

The same happens when I try to access it from other device. Output form `netstat`

```
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29622/python
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

on the other hand `ssh` works in both usages. No iptables running on that machine.

**EDIT**

Interesting

```
$ sudo nmap -sS 192.168.1.1/32
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-17 00:20 CEST
Nmap scan report for XXXXX.home (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
222/tcp  open  rsh-spx
5500/tcp open  hotline

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.42 seconds
$ sudo nmap -sS localhost/32
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-09-17 00:20 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
222/tcp  open  rsh-spx
631/tcp  open  ipp
5000/tcp open  upnp
5001/tcp open  commplex-link
5500/tcp open  hotline
8600/tcp open  asterix

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.44 seconds
```

Comment: I'd say your service was configured to only listen on the `lo` (localhost) interface, not on all interfaces/IPs. SSH listens on all interfaces by default.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem, thanks :) you can post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SSH listens on all interfaces. I think the services you're running are only listening on the localhost interface (`lo` or `127.0.0.1`). By correctly configuring the relevant service you can listen on all interfaces.

For example, Tor could be configured thus:

```
SocksListenAddress 0.0.0.0:8050
```

Apache `VirtualHost` definitions specify `*:80`, and so on.